# How to Access JSON from AJAX in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This is the JSON being sent back from the server:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1501796759610,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.validation.BindException",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "MVS0001.movieCriteria",
        "MVS0001"
      ],
      "arguments": null,
      "defaultMessage": "Empty Input",
      "objectName": "movieCriteria",
      "code": "MVS0001"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Validation failed for object='movieCriteria'. Error count: 1",
  "path": "\/movies\/search"
}
```

I want to print the default message and tried to access it like:

```
data.errors[0].defaultMessage but got errors.

alert(data) prints [object Object] 
alert(data.status) prints 400
alert(data.errors) prints undefined
alert(data.responseText.errors) prints undefined
alert(data.errors[0]) throws an error
alert(JSON.stringify(data)) prints {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"timestamp\":1501797911696,\"status\":400,\"error\":\"Bad Request\",\"exception\":\"org.springframework.validation.BindException\",\"errors\":[{\"codes\":[\"MVS0001.movieCriteria\",\"MVS0001\"],\"arguments\":null,\"defaultMessage\":\"Empty Input\",\"objectName\":\"movieCriteria\",\"code\":\"MVS0001\"}],\"message\":\"Validation failed for object='movieCriteria'. Error count: 1\",\"path\":\"/movies/search\"}","responseJSON":{"timestamp":1501797911696,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.validation.BindException","errors":[{"codes":["MVS0001.movieCriteria","MVS0001"],"arguments":null,"defaultMessage":"Empty Input","objectName":"movieCriteria","code":"MVS0001"}],"message":"Validation failed for object='movieCriteria'. Error count: 1","path":"/movies/search"},"status":400,"statusText":"error"}
```

I feel like the Ajax call I am using is not parsing the data properly, but using JSON.parse I am getting errors.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: searchUrl,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    success: function(data){
        alert('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In the success function, it should be `JSON.parse()` instead of `JSON.stringify`

Comment: You can console.log(data) and check developer console to see what you receieve in ajax success, also can check network tab of developer console to analyse your request

Comment: It's not a CORS issue the url is valid. I tested the service already for that. I am getting the right data back, the issue is only when I am trying to access it.

Comment: looking more closely, you want to `JSON.parse(data.responseText)` to "get" the result as a javascript object - odd, since you are passing in `dataType: 'json'` and according to jQuery documentation `"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.`

Comment: @GerritLuimstra He has `dataType: 'json'` so jQuery automatically parses it.

Comment: Using JSON.parse(data.responseText).errors[0].defaultMessage worked. Maybe it's because responseText was a nested object coming from the service I had to parse it again?

Comment: @Barmar, that's exactly what should happen, but looking at `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` it looks like it doesn't ... wonder what version of jQuuery is being used here

Comment: I am using 3.2.1 jQuery

Comment: Your `error:` function is being run, not the `success:` function. You're not showing the JSON response, you're showing the `jqXHR` object.

Comment: You need to check the server to see why it's reporting a `400` error code.

Comment: It's throwing a 400 because I'm not sending data. I have custom validation logic and when I don't send data it sends an error saying why. I want to print that error on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I was able to resolve this issue with this:

```
alert(JSON.parse(data.responseText).errors[0].defaultMessage);
```

Thanks!